# ASP.NET Web API 2.2 application won't activate for POST request

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, gzip

## The rundown

> Note: that my local server is **IISExpress**. I haven't tried deploying my application to IIS yet because I can't produce the desired behavior locally.

I'm trying to POST a body that's been GZipped client-side to my Web API.
I can get responses GZipped by simply communicating to IIS my `Accept-Encoding: gzip` but sending GZipped request bodies has been much more problematic.

I tried communicating `Content-Encoding: gzip` and copy-pasting the gzipped response into the body of my request(that obviously didn't work because I passed the binary through Unicode when I moved it through my clipboard).

I tried `<add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />` to my dynamicTypes list inside the `<httpCompression>` configuration block on my server.

I tried duplicating this configuration to my `<system.WebServer>` configuration block inside my application's web.config.

I tried creating a custom DelegatingHandler and I added a client-side Fiddler rule that would allow me to paste Unicode json into my request bodies and have Fiddler perform the GZip compression just before the request went out.

None of this is allowing my client to send a GZipped body to be received and decompressed by the server.

> Note also: The `Content-Type` of my POST body is `application/json`. When I sent my GZipped BODY(Section 2 of Detail below), I received an error about the GZip magic number in the header.  This was with [copy+pasted] content from one Fiddler response into a subsequent Fiddler request, so the binary content passed through the clipboard.  It is expected that this *might* fail having been converted to Unicode when it was copied to the clipboard. The most relevant piece of this is that it generates an explicit server error; *the server acknowledged it by virtue of responding with an Internal Server Error*

> Note finally: With a DelegatingHandler and a client-side call to `Utilities.GzipCompress()`, the server never acknowledges receipt of the request. If I comment out the compression line, the server acknowledges the request.

### What is causing this?

### How does this get corrected?

---

## The detail

So here's what got me here:

1]  I was able to simply ask for `Accept-Encoding: gzip` and IIS honored my request with GZipped responses.  Before making any configuration changes to `<httpCompression>` or adding a DelegatingHandler, I first tried to POST this GZipped content back to the server on a different request, while communicating `Content-Encoding: gzip`  When I did this, my application activated the appropriate controller and routed my request to the appropriate controller, but the Body would not deserialize, ostensibly because it tried to treat the compressed binary data as if it were clear text `Content-Type: application/json`. My client (Fiddler) received a `400 Bad Request`

> Note that to chain the gzipped response to the body of my test request, I passed the binary data through my clipboard. I knew this would not "just work"(passing through the clipboard transfers the binary data through UTF-8 -I think..maybe UTF-16...not terribly important) but I wanted to see what behavior I would actually get. The important part is that IIS and ASP.NET appear to have completely ignored my `Content-Encoding` header.

2] I then modified `httpCompression` inside my applicationHost.config to include `application/json` and `application/json; charset=utf8` in my list of types supporting dynamic compression

```
<httpCompression directory="%TEMP%\iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%IIS_BIN%\gzip.dll" />
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

I reissued my request from [**1**] and I received a 500 response prior to controller activation:

> `The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream.`

> Unable to decompress request using
>   compressor'System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Core.Compressors.GZipCompressor'

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred."
,"ExceptionMessage":"Unable to decompress request using compressor'System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Core.Compressors.GZipCompressor'"
,"ExceptionType":"System.Exception"
,"StackTrace":"   at Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server.BaseServerCompressionHandler.<DecompressRequest>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server.BaseServerCompressionHandler.<HandleDecompression>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server.BaseServerCompressionHandler.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
,"InnerException":
 {
   "Message":"An error has occurred."
  ,"ExceptionMessage":"The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream."
  ,"ExceptionType":"System.IO.InvalidDataException","StackTrace":"   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.IO.Stream.<CopyToAsyncInternal>d__27.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Core.Compressors.BaseCompressor.<Pump>d__9.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Core.Compressors.BaseCompressor.<Decompress>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Core.HttpContentOperations.<DecompressContent>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n

   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
   at Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server.BaseServerCompressionHandler.<DecompressRequest>d__19.MoveNext()"}}
```

3] I introduced a DelegatingHandler to my Composition space that triggers only on POST requests.

> CompressedRequestHandler.cs

```
public class CompressedRequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
        { 
            if (Compressed(request))
            {
                request.Content = Decompress(request);
            }
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
    private bool Compressed(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if ( request.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding == null) return false;
        if (!request.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip")) return false;

        return true;
    }
    private HttpContent Decompress(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        Stream output = new MemoryStream();
        Task task = request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            Stream input = t.Result;
            var gzip = new GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            gzip.CopyTo(output);
            gzip.Dispose();

            output.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        });
        task.Wait();
        HttpContent compressed = request.Content;
        HttpContent decompressed = new StreamContent(output);
        foreach(var header in compressed.Headers)
        {
            decompressed.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }

        return decompressed;
    }
```

To make sure that it is the first handler in my request stream, I Inserted it to index 0 inside my `Register(HttpConfiguration config)` method

```
config.MessageHandlers.Insert(0,new CompressedRequestHandler());
```

I also introduced a CustomRule in Fiddler to perform client-side compression onBeforeRequest, with two permutations (to test the rule itself)
1] actually performs GZip compression of the body
2] fires the rule but performs no Compression

```
//+================================================================================+
    //|[KAB] Trying to have Fiddler compress the clear Body prior to request.          |
    //|      Rationale: POSTing a gzipped response as a Request body is generating     |
    //|                 an internal server error                                       |
    //|   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
    //|   |The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing | |
    //|   |in a GZip stream.                                                         | |
    //|   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+ |
    //|   Goal is to see if passing through the clipboard is what is generating this   |
    //+================================================================================+
    if(oSession.requestBodyBytes != null && (oSession.oRequest.headers.Exists("Client.Request-Encoding")))
    {
        if(oSession.oRequest["Client.Request-Encoding"] == "gzip")
        {

           //+=================================================+
           //|Commenting these 2 lines prevents the Compression
           //|from actually occurring. When I disable compression
           //|of requestBodyBytes, the request goes out and is
           //|serviced as an uncompressed body by my application
           //|-------------------------------------------------
              oSession.requestBodyBytes = Utilities.GzipCompress(oSession.requestBodyBytes);
              oSession["Content-Length"] = oSession.requestBodyBytes.Length.ToString();
           //|-------------------------------------------------
           //+=================================================+

           oSession["ui-color"] = "green";
           oSession["ui-bold"] = "true";
        }else{
           oSession["ui-color"] = "crimson";
           oSession["ui-italics"] = "true";
           oSession.oRequest["Client.Request-Encoding.Error"] = "Rule not processed. gzip is the only supported Request-Encoding value";
        }
    }
```

### That brings you up to speed on the moving parts

> A note on the custom Rule (or a reiteration to draw attention to what I already said)  When I comment out the lines of the rule that perform the call to `GzipCompress(oSession.requestBodyBytes)`, my application wakes, my DelegatingHandler fires and everything processes as if the request was uncompressed.  Whenever the lines are enabled, my request goes out GZip compressed(confirmed through Composer) but my application never receives the request. The DelegatingHandler never fires.

Comment: Can you show the Api controller's POST method? It sounds like the compression is making the request body look like something that the controller isn't expecting.

Comment: @David I can show the POST method, but DelegatingHandlers fire before the HttpRouteDispatcher and ASP.NET does not route POST requests based on the content of their bodies, so I don't think it's relevant to my issue. If -after reading that- you still have a specific curiosity that you feel may be relevant, please let me know and I'll edit to update